# Encrypt javascript code to prevent javascript injection in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript

I'm going to store javascript code in the MongoDB (No-SQL) database.

But to prevent javascript injection I want to encrypt the javascript code which is in a string.

Is there a way to encrypt it and then decrypt it without having a defect javascript code?

Comment: What? I thought the point of NoSQL was that you're not going to be inviting injection problems by concatenating data into a string query?

Comment: @bobince: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/09/22/security-lessons-learned-from-the-diaspora-launch/ Read the headline: NoSQL Doesn’t Mean No SQL Injection

Comment: "But to prevent javascript injection..." And where would this injection happen?

Comment: Wow, they seriously added user input verbatim into a `function` string to be `exec`​ed. And that's not even the start of the mind-bogglingly basic security errors listed in that article. I think I'll not touch Diaspora with a barge pole.

Comment: Also, I hadn't really looked at Mongo before (it's not my NoSQL of choice), but having a general-purpose `eval`​able ‘where’ string (rather than, say, taking an inline `function() {...}` expression) looks like an annoying, slow and dangerous design decision. Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of stuff other the web considering this.

I suggest you have a look at jquery plugin encryption  [jquery plugin encryption](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/encryption)

I personnally have not used one of these encryption tools, but the integration seems pretty easy, 
and of course you should generate a random encryption key :

For instance here is the example of [jqCrypt](http://www.fluidbyte.net/jqcrypt-post-method-encryption):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqcrypt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      $('#form_id').jqcrypt({
          keyname:    'jqckval',
          randomkey:  false,
          key:        'some_key_value',
          callback: function(form){ 
              form.submit(); 
          }
      });
  });
</script>
```

And here should be the decrypting example

```
function c2sdecrypt($s,$k){
    $k = base64_decode(urldecode($k));
    $s = urldecode($s);
    $k = str_split(str_pad('', strlen($s), $k));
    $sa = str_split($s);
    foreach($sa as $i=>$v){
        $t = ord($v)-ord($k[$i]);
        $sa[$i] = chr( $t < 0 ?($t+256):$t);
    }
    return urldecode(join('', $sa));
 }
```

From the jqCrypt plugin.

The only strong point will be the generation of a strong hash in the web page, to encrypt
the value return from the Web Page Client.